# How to find and group similar permutations of 4 digits

Tags: python, permutation

I am not good at these, but please bear with me. I have a set of numbers from my database / list, all are 4 digit numbers with the numbers between and include 0000 through 9999.

Say the list is:

```
[1234, 4354, 6554, 2134, 3214, 5456, 9911, 1199]
```

Basically, I want to group them in such a way

```
1234, 2134, 3214 is group A
6554, 5456 is group B
9911, 1199 is group C
4354 is group D
```

where the list items in each group all contain the same numbers - i.e, Group A are all made up of the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4. Then I will find the len(group A), len(group B), len(group C), len(group D)...
and then sort them in decreasing manner.

How to do it?
And if list is huge, is the method still works ok?

Comment: It could just be me, but I don't understand the question. 

Comment: This is not a coding service. Have you tried any code of your own? How did it fail? If there was an error message, what is the full traceback? Also, must the groups be in the order you gave? For example, could your groups C and D be switched?

Comment: What is the grouping based on?

Comment: with same set of digit.

Comment: Yes, the grouping is based on same set of digits as @acw1668 said. Hi Rory Daulton, this is so hard for me that I don't even know how to start. The groups can be switched, just different grouping for different sets of numbers.

Comment: What if you convert the numbers to stings, and sort the characters, then see which ones are all the same and group them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do about naming the groups, but you can use `itertools.groupby` after converting the ints to strings, and sorting those characters

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [1234, 4354, 6554, 2134, 3214, 5456, 9911, 1199]

# ints to (int, sorted str)
s = map(lambda x: (x, ''.join(sorted(str(x)))), l)

# sort the list for groupby
s.sort(key=lambda kv: kv[1])

# print out just the ints of the groups
for _, g in groupby(s, lambda kv: kv[1]):
    print map(lambda kv: kv[0], g)
```

Output

```
[9911, 1199]
[1234, 2134, 3214]
[4354]
[6554, 5456]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (tested in Python 2.7.10) solution:

```
def index(number):
    digits = list(str(number))
    return ''.join(sorted(digits))

groups = {}
numbers = [1234, 4354, 6554, 2134, 3214, 5456, 9911, 1199]

for number in numbers:
    key = index(number)

    if key not in groups:
        groups[key] = []

    groups[key].append(number)

print groups.values() # [[1234, 2134, 3214], [4354], [6554, 5456], [9911, 1199]]
```

The key to this solution is to take the digits of each number and sort them, then use that result as the dictionary key. `index()` is just a succinct way of generating the digit-ordered form of each number.

Comment: Thanks for the help